# How to distinguish input from the return value of body in while-no-input?

Tags: iteration

> `(while-no-input &rest BODY)`
>
> Execute BODY only as long as there's no pending input.
>
> If input arrives, that ends the execution of BODY, and while-no-input
> returns t.  Quitting makes it return nil. If BODY finishes,
> while-no-input returns whatever value BODY produced.

If the BODY returns `t` then there is no way to distinguish it from the input interruption. One way could be to check if the return value is `t` in the BODY itself and then return certain value like `293851932832985`. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4):

The Elisp manual (do `C-h i g (elisp) RET i while-no-input RET` for more details - learning to use Info and the Info manuals is a good investment of your time) suggests the following:

> If you want to be able to distinguish all possible values computed
> by BODY from both kinds of abort conditions, write the code like
> this:
>
> ```
>      (while-no-input
>        (list
>          (progn . BODY)))
> ```

The rest of the description in the manual is also worth reading because there are a couple of wrinkles that are not covered by the doc string of `while-no-input`.